# Ocultar elemento da activity

Tags: android

Estou usando uma activity que dispõe dos seguintes elementos:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    tools:context=".MapsActivity" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/evento_btn"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
    android:layout_width="66dp"
    android:layout_height="66dp"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="215dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
    android:drawableBottom="@drawable/button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/manu_btn"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/evento_btn"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginEnd="-86dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
    android:drawableBottom="@drawable/menu_btn" />
```

E estou tentando ocultar os elementos quando o usuário clicar na tela, para dar mais espaço para o usuário interagir com o mapa (mesmo principio do google maps quando vc clica no mapa e o menu e os outros botões são ocultados). Para isso tentei o seguinte código:

```
    manu_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.evento_btn);
    evento_btn =(Button) findViewById(R.id.evento_btn);
    manu_btn.setText("+0");
    evento_btn.setText("+0");
     handler = new Handler();
     handler.postDelayed(runnable,7000);


}

Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        evento_btn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        evento_btn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    }
};
```

Funciona, mas não cumpre o que foi proposto. Alguma ideia de como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "Eu preciso que os botões fiquem ocultos apenas quando houver o toque na tela e que eles retornem quando o usuário tocar outra vez."

Utilize o `onUserInteraction` da sua activity, segue um exemplo:

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final long DELAY_MS = 7000;
    private boolean hidden = false;
    private Runnable hideRunnable;
    private Handler hideHandler = new Handler();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // ...

        hideRunnable = () -> { // Java 8 Lambda
            hidden = true;
            manu_btn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            evento_btn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        };

        // Quando a activity for criada, se o usuário não interagir com ela,
        // os botões serão automaticamente esondidos em 7 segundos
        hideHandler.postDelayed(hideRunnable, DELAY_MS);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUserInteraction() {
        super.onUserInteraction();

        // Cancelar ações pendentes
        hideHandler.removeCallbacks(hideRunnable);

        if (hidden) {
            manu_btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            evento_btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            hidden = false;
        } else {
            hideHandler.postDelayed(hideRunnable, DELAY_MS);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Muito obrigada!

Answer (score 2):

Tenta trocar o:

```
evento_btn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

por

```
evento_btn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

O View.INVISIBLE vai esconder o item, porém vai manter o espaço dele, já o View.GONE vai remover até o espaço do objeto da tela.

Comment: Sim, no entanto eu preciso que os botões fiquem ocultos apenas quando houver o toque na tela e que eles retornem quando o usuário tocar outra vez.

Comment: Você pode fazer um onClickListener que tenha um booleano pra saber se foi clicado ou não, vc já conseguiu resolver?

Answer (score 0):

`evento_btn.setVisibility(View.GONE);` pra "esconder" o botão e `evento_btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` pra mostrar o botão novamente

Você pode usar

`if(evento_btn.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
evento_btn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
} else if (evento_btn.getVisibility() == View.GONE){
evento_btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}`

Answer (score 0):

INVISIBLE

> Essa visão é invisível, mas ainda ocupa espaço para propósitos de layout.

GONE

> Essa visualização é invisível e não ocupa espaço para fins de layout.

Como você pode ler, INVISIBLE ocultará a visualização, mas ocupará seu espaço, mas a GONE ocultará a visão e perderá o espaço da visualização principal.